# Add layer using popup in ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I would like to be able to add a new feature layer within a popup window from an arcgis server.  For example (purely hypothetical), you click on a state and it has 2 options: fire departments and police stations.  You can then click on one of those options to add it to the map

Comment: so do you want drop-down list in the pop-up ? so that after selecting appropriate layer it will add on existing layer. Please explain your question. If possible add some screenshot..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood question 100% but this might help you [Custom popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_extendInfowindow.).
You can add `onClick` event to the html "a" control and call function in which you can add layer on the map.